# "on the verge" Vs "on the edge" Vs "At the edge" Vs "at the verge"

Tags: usage, phrases

I know this can be flagged as off topic, because it a bit broad, but let me give it a try. Is there any difference between these phrases:

- on the verge of
- on the edge of
- at the verge of
- at the edge of

> Suppose that you want to say, something is at the boundary of two opposing states, like the country was at the edge of chaos.

I've checked the dictionaries and I honestly think all of them are interchangeable. However, it seems "on the edge of" is far more common among the four according to Ngram:
[image]

Comment: Along with "brink", "at/on the brink", all of those seem to me to have meanings that are so close that any differences would be dependent on the variety of English (British, American, NZ, etc.), and maybe even on region within a particular variety. The same goes for how idiomatic the various expressions are. For instance "on" seems more natural to me with both "edge" and "verge", but "at" doesn't sound *wrong* either. ...but what do people in, say, Jamaica think?

Comment: Please leave a comment after smashing down-vote button, that would make the word a better place for every one in the long run.